# Only send welcome DM to users of specific server in discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I have a discord bot who resides in multiple servers, however I would like to either have join messages for each server or ensure my bot only sends the welcome message to those joining one of them.

```
@client.event #Send new members of the server a message
async def on_member_join(member): #Run when a member joins
    await member.create_dm() #Create a DM chat with the new user
    await member.dm_channel.send(f"Heya, {member.name}! [ETC OF WELCOME MESSAGE]")
    print(f'User DM sent:\n----------\nUser: {member.name}\n----------')
```

According to the documentation, the only parameter of `on_member_join` is `member`, so is this not possible?
I have been attempting to send the DM based on server IDs.
After some research, I saw `ctx.author.send`, but that didn't work:

```
  File "REDACTED", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "REDACTED", line 34, in on_member_join
    await ctx.author.send(f"Heya, {member.name}! REDACTED")
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Here is the full code, in its current form.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx):
    current_server = ctx.guild.id
    if current_server == server_id:
        await ctx.author.send(f"Heya, {member.name}! REDACTED")
        print(f'User DM sent:\n----------\nUser: {member.name}\n----------')
```

Comment: Why can't you combine the `if` from the last example with the DM code from the first example to send welcome messages only to one server?

Comment: @mousetail I tried that, that creates the error I've written above.

Comment: What error do you get in that case? A member has no "author" so the second example makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join) provide the signature for on_member_join event. So you can use member object provided by the event to get the id of server joined and compare it against stored guild id.

For a single server:

```py
# stored_guild_id must be defined before this code appears

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id == stored_guild_id:
        await member.send(f"Welcome to the server!")
```

If you have a bunch of servers you can use a list of servers:

```py
# stored_guild_ids must be defined above this code. For example:
# stored_guild_ids = [id1, id2]
# where id1 and id2 are guild ids

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id in stored_guild_ids:
        await member.send(f"Welcome to the server!")
```

You can also store it as a dictionary and have separate greeting for each server.

```py
# welcome_messages must be defined. For example:
# welcome_messages = {
#    guild_id: "Welcome there!", 
#    guild_id2: 'Hello there!'
#  }
# Again guild_id and guild_id2 are actual guild ids

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id in welcome_messages.keys():
        await member.send(welcome_messages[member.guild.id])
```

Depending on the use case this might also be extended to store welcome messages in files and have a command to edit welcome messages from discord using a command. You can also set message to have a field such as:
`welcome_messages = {my_guild_id: "Hello {0}! Welcome to server")`
and use
`await member.send(welcome_messages[guild_id].format(member.mention))`
which would replace `0` with mention of new user.

Comment: Hopefully this comment isn't a bother, but it seems that the code you suggested has stopped working? I've looked at the docs but can't see any changes that would explain it. Would you have any knowledge as to why?

Comment: What do you mean it has stopped working? Is the message not being sent/is the mention not working/are there any errors? It might be better to ask a new question with above information.